# Implementation of Expression.Assign in .Net 3.5 with same signature?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, expression, expression-trees

`Expression.Assign` isn't available before .NET 4. I need to implementation under .NET 3.5 of this method with original signature:

```
public static BinaryExpression Assign(
    Expression left,
    Expression right
)
```

Clarification: I'm not looking for a way to use this method in the some case. I need to implement the general case.

Comment: You can't. You'd need to recreate the `Expression` classes entirely. The reason is that the expression-tree-to-IL compiler used by `expression.Compile()` contains the logic to figure out the IL codes to use, and if .NET 3.5 doesn't have `Expression.Assign`, the compiler won't be able to recognise it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get exact equivalent since there is no `ExpressionType.Assign`, but it's possible to make something similar:

```
public static class ExpressionEx
{
    public static BinaryExpression Assign(Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        var assign = typeof(Assigner<>).MakeGenericType(left.Type).GetMethod("Assign");

        var assignExpr = Expression.Add(left, right, assign);

        return assignExpr;
    }

    private static class Assigner<T>
    {
        public static T Assign(ref T left, T right)
        {
            return (left = right);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it for generating assignments:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static Action<object, object> MakeSetter(PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var objectParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), string.Empty);
        var valueParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), string.Empty);
        var setterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(
            ExpressionEx.Assign(
                Expression.Property(
                    Expression.Convert(objectParameter, info.DeclaringType),
                    info),
                Expression.Convert(valueParameter, info.PropertyType)),
            objectParameter,
            valueParameter);

        return setterExpression.Compile();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var property = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Data");

        var setter = MakeSetter(property);
        setter(foo, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Data);
    }
}
```

If you don't really need `BinaryExpression` as a return type you could use `Expression.Call` instead of `Add` so it would be not so hackish.

Comment: You can even put the generic `Assign`-method into the `ExpressionEx`-class to avoid the annoying private class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't.

Here's the reasons:

1. `ExpressionType` enumeration doesn't contain `Assign` member in 3.5.
2. I tried using wrong ExpressionType and creating a binary expression using `Expression.MakeBinary()` with my method, but that method gets ignored. (Resulting BinaryExpression has either standard `Method`, or `Method` = null.)
3. You can't assign `Method` in instance -- it's readonly and the class is sealed so you can't work around it in the derived class.

But since they've included that `method` argument to `MakeBinary()`, there still might exist some workaround... I'm not 100% sure that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the splution of Konstantin Oznobihin here´s a slighty modified one which contains the `MethodCallExpression` instead of a `BinaryExpression`:

```
public class ExpressionEx
{
    public static Expression Assign(Expression left, Expression right)
    {
        var method = typeof(ExpressionEx).GetMethod("Assign", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).MakeGenericMethod(left.Type);
        return Expression.Call(method, left, right);
    }
    private static void Assign<T>(ref T left, T right)
    {
        left = right;
    }
}
```

This will create a delegate to the `Assign`-method within `ExpressionEx` and can now easily be used like this:

```
var expr = ExpressionEx.Assign(myInstanceExpression, newValueExpression);
```